# Pandas can't read in csv file produced by Numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a comma delimited csv file that is exported by Mac Numbers, and I am trying to read it into a dataframe, but get an error message:

```
df = pd.read_csv('game.csv', dtype={"rating": str}, error_bad_lines='ignore', encoding='utf8', sep=',')
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/congminmin/nlp/data_collection/crawler/data/game/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('game_app_apple.missing.url.csv', dtype={"rating": str}, error_bad_lines='ignore', encoding='utf8', sep=',')
  File "/Users/congminmin/.venv/data_collection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/congminmin/.venv/data_collection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/Users/congminmin/.venv/data_collection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/Users/congminmin/.venv/data_collection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/Users/congminmin/.venv/data_collection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 426, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ignore'
```

Is my csv not valid? But it is produced by Numbers. Even if I removed the dtype parameter, it got the same issue. If i removed the error_bad_lines='ignore', I got the following error:

```
File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 860, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 875, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 929, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 916, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2071, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

The csv exported by Numbers is comma delimited, and I want to read into a dataframe and output as tab delimited, but got the problem above.

Add data: The original data is Chinese and the 'rating' in code above is actually '评分' translation in actual data below:

I had to take a screenshot, since it is recognized as spam by stackoverflow:

[image]

Comment: Can you open the csv file in a text editor and paste the first few rows in your question?

Comment: It seems one value should be an integer, but it is not. How many columns does it have? Should be possible for you to do this `dtype={"rating": str}` for all fields... Set all of them as `str` so, you could figure out if it is the file itself or the conversion as I mentioned.

Comment: @PauloMarques I removed 'dtype={"rating": str}' and it is the same thing.

Comment: The idea, was not to remove it, but insert there the other fields (eg: `dtype={"rating": str, "otherfield": str....}`

Comment: I believe that you can test it doing something like `df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', dtype=str)`. So, all fields will be a `str` type... At least for testing purposes.

Comment: I opened it in MS excel and save it as csv again, then pandas can read it without problem.